# JQuery selected value if statement couldn't compare right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was testing to see the if statement work by compare selected value to string then show pop up alert. However, the alert result always say "off" no matter what I specific select. It seem that the if statement did not compare correct. Here my code,

```
$("#options").change(function(){
                                var selected = $("option:selected", this).val();

                                if(selected == 'line 2')
                                {
                                    alert("line 2");
                                }
                                else if(selected == 'line 3')
                                {
                                    alert("line 3");
                                }
                                else if(selected == 'line 4')
                                {
                                    alert("line 4");
                                }
                                else if(selected == 'line 8')
                                {
                                    alert("line 8");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    alert("off");
                                }

                    });
```

HTML dropdown code,

```
<select id="options">
                <optgroup label="Caption">
                    <option value="off1">Off</option>
                    <option selected value="2 line">2 Lines</option>
                    <option value="3 line">3 lines</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Transcript">
                    <option value="off2">Off</option>
                    <option value="4 line">4 Lines</option>
                    <option value="8 line">8 lines</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
```

Comment: Please format your code and markup in questions to remove excess white space to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value is `2 line` and you are comparing with `line 2` (*for example*)

Try this;

```
var selected = $("option:selected", this).val();
    if(selected == '2 line')
       {
         alert("line 2");
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of all of your options is backwards from your test.

```
$("#options").change(function(){
                            var selected = $("option:selected", this).val();
                            alert(selected); 
                            if(selected == 'line 2')
                            {
                                alert("line 2");
                            }
                            else if(selected == 'line 3')
                            {
                                alert("line 3");
                            }
                            else if(selected == 'line 4')
                            {
                                alert("line 4");
                            }
                            else if(selected == 'line 8')
                            {
                                alert("line 8");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alert("off");
                            }

                });
```

Adding in that alert will help you test against the right value.

Comment: yeah I wasn't pay close attention to that

Answer (score 0):

The values your are comparing to and the values in the html do not match.

Answer (score 0):

You have the line texts reverted in your test and you might also be better of using an array for this.

```
(function() {
    var selectionValues = [
        '2 line',
        '3 line',
        '4 line',
        '8 line'
    ];


    $("#options").change(function() {
        var selected = $("option:selected", this).val();

        var index = selectionValues.indexOf(selected);
        var result;

        if (index !== -1) {
            result = selectionValues[index];
        }
        else {
            result = "Off";
        }

        alert(result);
    });
})();
```